# Express-JWT authentication middleware error: Next is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, jwt, express-jwt

I am building a frontend application that uses 2FA in addition to JWT to authorize a authenticated account. The middleware is set up as such:

```
const router = require('express').Router()
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const exjwt = require('express-jwt')
const jwtMW = exjwt({
    secret: 'testing out a secret',
})

const getBearerToken = (header, callback) => {
    if (header) {
        console.log(header)
        const token = header.split(' ')
        if (token) {
            return callback(null, token[0])
        } else {
            return callback('Malformed bearer token', null)
        }
    } else {
        return callback('Missing authorization header', null)
    }
}

const validateToken = (req, res, next) => {
    getBearerToken(req.headers['authorization'], (error, token) => {
        if (error) {
            return res.status(401).json({ success: false, message: error })
        }
        jwt.verify(token, jwtMW, (error, decodedToken) => {
            if (error) {
                return res.status(401).send({
                    success: false,
                    error: 'Invalid authorization token',
                })
            }
            if (decodedToken.authorized) {
                req.decodedToken = decodedToken
                next()
            } else {
                return res
                    .status(401)
                    .send({ success: false, error: '2fa is required' })
            }
        })
    })
}
```

I run it on protected routes like this:

```
router.get('/:id/profile', validateToken, (req, res) => {
    User.findById(req.params.id)
        .then(user => res.json(user))
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err))
})
```

**EDIT, ADDITIONAL ROUTE**

And another route that fetches the token here:

```
router.post('/verifycheck', (req, res) => {
    let tel = `+1${req.body.tel}`
    const code = req.body.code
    getBearerToken(req.headers['authorization'], (error, token) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error)
            return res.status(401).json({ success: false, message: error })
        }
        if (!code) {
            return res.status(401).json({
                success: false,
                message: 'A verification code is required',
            })
        }
        jwt.verify(token, jwtMW, (error, decodedToken) => {
           // client refers to Twilio Verify service //
            client.verify
                .services('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
                .verificationChecks.create({ to: tel, code: code })
                .then(verification_check => {
                    console.log(error)
                    console.log(decodedToken)
                    if (verification_check.valid) {
                        decodedToken.authorized = true
                        console.log(decodedToken)
                        var token = jwt.sign(decodedToken, jwtMW, {
                            expiresIn: 129600,
                        })
                        return res.json({ verification_check, token })
                    } else {
                        return res.status(401).json({
                            success: false,
                            message: 'Invalid verification code',
                        })
                    }
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    res.json(err.message)
                    console.log(err)
                })
        })
    })
})
```

And it throws an error that crashes the server, saying

```
TypeError: next is not a function
    at middleware (D:\Users\Capstone Design\Desktop\learningmongodb\mern-rod\node_modules\express-jwt\lib\index.js:76:16)
    at Object.module.exports [as verify] (D:\Users\Capstone Design\Desktop\learningmongodb\mern-rod\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\verify.js:94:10)
    at getBearerToken (D:\Users\Capstone Design\Desktop\learningmongodb\mern-rod\backend\routes\index.js:109:13)     
    at getBearerToken (D:\Users\Capstone Design\Desktop\learningmongodb\mern-rod\backend\routes\index.js:22:20)      
    at router.post (D:\Users\Capstone Design\Desktop\learningmongodb\mern-rod\backend\routes\index.js:97:5)
```

I see where the error is happening, but I'm unsure of how to fix this error.

**EDIT**

I realized that jwt.verify doesn't accept callbacks as an argument. When I removed the callback function and ran the verify function in a try/catch statement, things worked as expected.

```
const validateToken = (req, res, next) => {
    getBearerToken(req.headers['authorization'], (error, token) => {
        if (error) {
            return res.status(401).json({ success: false, message: error })
        }
        let decoded = ''
        try {
            decoded = jwt.verify(token, 'testing out a secret')
        } catch (error) {
            return res.status(401).send({
                success: false,
                error: 'Invalid authorization token',
            })
        }
        if (decoded.authorized) {
            req.decodedToken = decoded
            next()
        } else {
            return res
                .status(401)
                .send({ success: false, error: '2fa is required' })
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Have you export your `validateToken` and import it in your `router` file?

Comment: @TitusSutioFanpula the validateToken function is defined in the router file.

Comment: Why you separate that code? why you don't post all code in that route in this question, so we can know where's the problem. Maybe you can update your code in your question.

Comment: @TitusSutioFanpula this is the only route that uses this authentication middleware. And the route is very simple

Comment: I want to see how you declare your `router` variable.

Comment: @TitusSutioFanpula just added the router declaration at the top of the code.

Comment: Have you look at this path `learningmongodb\mern-rod\backend\routes\index.js:97:5`, because I've been try your code above and it's working fine.

Comment: @TitusSutioFanpula added that other route.

Comment: Maybe there's the error'. On line 97.

Comment: Can you add all code for routes\index.js?

Comment: @TitusSutioFanpula I figured out the problem.... jwt.verify isn't a function that takes a callback as an argument. When I removed the callback, the function worked as expected. Thanks for the prompts.